# flash loader problem

Tags: flash, loader, stage

I am have difficulties with a certain issue :
I have a main flash application that loads different content - games, applications and etc. In some games when it is loaded there is change in it's behavior of parts(movieclips) . For example without the loader-application you shoot and kill a person in content game but in the loader when you play with the same game you shoot and although the bullet has touched the person-mc nothing happens.
I hope I explain it ok)).
Any idea why is that happens?
thanks i advance

**update :**

Hi Malte Köhrer,
Thank you for your replies very much! It just drives me crazy - the answer is somewhere around here but is missed).
Here is the code - on Event.COMPLETE I change the position of the loaded content. I have another function that runs during the COMPLETE and it adds the parts that their placement is changed. The important that they are changed onCOMPLETE not before. 
thanks for your kind help.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(loader);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingFunc);
loader.load(new URLRequest(urlAdr));


function loadingFunc(event:Event):void
{

    var loaderInf:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;
    dispObj = loaderInf.loader;

    //dispObj.x = stage.stageWidth/2-loaderInf.width/2;  --------------- That how it was          before I changed root property
    //dispObj.y = stage.stageHeight/2-loaderInf.height/2;

    var mb:MovieClip = dispObj.loaderInfo.content as MovieClip; //----------- That how it's now
    mb.x = stage.stageWidth/2-loaderInf.width/2;
    mb.y = stage.stageHeight/2-loaderInf.height/2;

    //var app:App = new App(mb); This give the same resault as var mb:MovieClip = dispObj.loaderInfo.content as MovieClip;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the SWF files that you load actually use the root property to access its movieclips/buttons? If that's the case you might want to check where your Loader places the loaded SWF.

Comment: thanx for reply!
Could you please explain more what did you mean?
I add the Loader component with addChild method and the Loader loads into itself the content.
Maybe you can add some line of code for example?
  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Not much space for comments, so I'll try to keep it short and simple: If you have an HTML page that loads a SWF it loads it into "root". You on the other hand use a special loader-SWF that gets loaded into "root" then creates a loader and adds it to some movieclip, for example to "root.myLoadedSwf". If the SWF that you load with your Loader tries to access its movieclips/buttons via root.some_movieclip_name it will fail since the SWF you just loaded got added to the MovieClip "root.myLoadedSwf" - and not "root".

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid using root would be initalizing your app like this from the timeline:

```
var app:App=new App(this);
```

In that case you pass the App a reference to the movieclip that is containing the script, no matter if it's in root or anywhere else. Here's an example of how the class could look like:

```
class App{
    public var appRoot:MovieClip=null;
    function App(appRoot:MovieClip){
        this.appRoot=appRoot:
    }
    function setHeadline(text:String):void{
         appRoot.textField.text=text;
    }
}
```

Now you got the reference to the movieclip saved and can use it to access (example: setHeadline() function) everything without worrying about root not containing what you expect it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and example! But somehow it didn't work for me or I just didn't take it the correct way.
this line: 
var app:App=new App(this);


I implement in my main application that is the kind of loader. Is it correct?
The class App I import into the main application. Is is what did you mean or I'm wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That example just shows how you could avoid using root inside the movies that you load. Read this for some info on how root works: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#root

Comment: Stackoverflow is not really a discussion forum and this is not really the original problem anymore either. I suggest you start a new post.

Comment: hi Malte Köhrer.
i have posted a new question about this issue this topic, i would applicate  if you could check it out.
p.s:do you think it would be better to use the private channel for this discussion(e-mail or p.m) ?